Is there a compare-and-swap mechanism on remote git refs?
git-update-ref has a form that takes three arguments: <ref> <new-oid> [<old-oid>].
This allows compare-and-swap updates on local refs.
However, I have not found a similar option for git push or in the definition of refspecs.
Is there a command to do an equivalent compare-and-swap operation on remote refs?
Equivalently, if there was a way to "delete ref iff equals <old_oid>", that would also work.

Look at push force-with-lease

@RaymondChen I actually did look at force-with-lease but it empirically seems to work only with branches not arbitrary refs. I asked about an equivalent to update-ref because I seek a solution that works with all refs.

git push --force-with-lease=refs/dirs/xyz:99ec841199e9affef189bd1ec001f21f5f6b7a76 origin 3e0664f6b7766d969d55c9ac921ec450fc1b5a63 fatal: 3e0664f6b7766d969d55c9ac921ec450fc1b5a63 cannot be resolved to branch

You cannot push just an arbitrary ref: git push origin 3e0664f doesn't work. You must tell Git what remote ref you want to update: git push origin 3e0664f:xyz

Thanks, I stand corrected! I had made the incorrect assumption that git would infer the ref from the --force-with-lease option, but clearly that was wrong. Thus, force-with-lease addresses this question, as far as I can tell.
